# Java: check, if URL is allowed by robots.txt

Tags: java, web-crawler

Given that an application has:

- robots.txt contents,
- URL of interest and
- browsing entity metadata (like user-agent string, etc)

how to check if a particular URL is allowed by *robots.txt*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[crawler-commons](https://github.com/crawler-commons/crawler-commons) is a Java API which can parse robots files given a particular robot name and return the rules applicable for that robot. The rules have an `isAllowed(String url)` method which does what you are after.

Comment: Cool. That's exactly what is was looking for.

Comment: @DenisKulagin worth marking my answer as accepted then?

Comment: That's for sure!